# Como exibir a SQL History no SQL Developer?

Tags: pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Necessito visualizar todas alterais em uma procedure.
A ferramenta SQL Developer tem uma barra de ferramenta que 
armazena um historico de alterações.

Como posso habilitar/visualizar ?

**Imagem da fucionalidade**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZTQP.png

Comment: Meu objetivo é visualizar o histórico de alterações em uma procedure. Afim de identificar o que foi alterado

Comment: só consigo visualizar as alteções em aquivos .sql as procedures não consigo visualizar o histórico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nas telas abaixo basta clicar na aba history para visualizar as alterações 
feitas o arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]